# Creating a Button Click Event and Validating TextBoxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, datagrid

I am having so much trouble with this. I have looked everywhere so I hope someone can either explain to me how to do this or show me. Here's my problem:

I have a DataGrid filled with DataBound Items (ItemTemplate) which was created using ASP.Net.

My reason for the `ItemTemplates` over a regular `DataBound` field is to enable the Edit Mode of the DataGrid. In my `ItemTemplates`, I have labels to display the data and two option buttons (Edit/Delete). I've got the buttons working in the code behind (C#).

*Edit* places the DataGrid in Edit Mode. In the `EditItemTemplates` I've got `DropDownLists`, `TextBoxe`s, and a *Save* button in place of the *Edit* button.

The *Save* button also works with the code I've written for it. All-in-all, the DataGrid works beautifully and displays everything neatly. However, there is one final job I want the *Save* button to do: **I want it to check the TextBoxes and validate that the values entered match the criteria I have set** (keep in mind that these are in `EditItemTemplates`).

I have Javascript already written that will check for validation. I want a modal window (that I have already set up) to display and I want the CSS of the TextBoxes in question to change.

I want to do this using Javascript but my problem is that I can't check for the *Save* button to create the `Click` event and I can't 'locate' the TextBoxes to validate them. Is there a way I can 'find' those elements while the DataGrid is in Edit Mode?

Here's a small bit of the code used to create the DataGrid if it helps:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgCamsizer" CssClass="data" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                GridLines="None" OnItemCommand="dgCamsizer_ItemCommand" ShowHeader="true">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="infoHeaderDG">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Operator</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Operator" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Operator") %>'
                                runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="EditOper" Width="40px" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Operator") %>'
                                runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="infoHeaderDG"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>

                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="infoHeaderDG">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Edit" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Save" Text="Save" CommandName="Save" runat="server" /></EditItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="infoHeaderDG"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
     </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Perhaps I should re-phase my question: **I managed to 'find' the `TextBoxes` thanks to Zetlen. I've also managed to get the values. Now... How do I use those values to test for validation?**

Here is the code I used to get the values:

```
$("#<%=dgCamsizer.ClientID %> :text").each(function () {
                        alert($(this).val());
                    });
```

Comment: If you've answered your question, please post the answer here and accept it so that others will know it's resolved. Don't edit the title -- Stack Overflow has other visual cues to tell users that questions have been answered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve my own problems and answer my own question. I was able to get the id's of all of the `TextBoxes` and I even placed them into an array to be used for my validations. Here's what I used to do all of this:

```
var i = 0;
var data = [];
$("#<%=dgCamsizer.ClientID %> :text").each(function () {
  data[i] = $(this).attr("id");
  i++;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET webforms are hard to work with in JavaScript, because the IDs of your HTML elements change during the page lifecycle! The input you're calling "EditOper" will get an HTML ID of something like "dgCamSizer_ctl102_EditOper". One thing you can do is collect these elements on pageload in a cache of DOM element references. I recommend using jQuery or a similar DOM querying library.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $editorElms = {},
            idSeparator = "_"; // the underscore is ASP.NET's default ID separator, but this can be changed if you wish with the IDSeparator property.
        $('#dgCamSizer input').each(function() {
            $editorElms[this.id.split('_').pop()] = $(this);
        });

    // now you can access every input using the $editorElms hash.
    // e.g.    
        function someValidationRoutine() {

            if (!$editorElms.EditOper.val()) {
               someErrorDisplayer("EditOper must not be blank.");
               return false;
            }

        }
    })
</script>
```

And, again using jQuery, the Save button shouldn't be too tough to find.

```
var $saveButton = $('#dgCamSizer :submit[value=Save]');
```

So you can bind the event that way:

```
$saveButton.click(function(e) {
    if (!someValidationRoutine()) {
          e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This is not the most high-performance solution--selectors of that complexity are always a bit slower. But it gets the job done without messing too much with the DataGrid.

Comment: I can kind of see what you are doing. Only thing I don't understand is how it finds the elements in Edit Mode. I ran an alert and it did pick up the change from Read Only to Edit but when I tried to find the value of what was in the TextBox, it came up as undefined. I tried to tweek around with the code but since I don't fully understand it, I don't feel like there's much I can do. :(

Thank you for answering. Sadly, I'm still getting the same result.